# How to call a "sub" .inputrc? (Like in .bashrc, where you can "source sub_script.sh")

Tags: bash, bashrc, inputrc

My `~/.bashrc` contains exactly one line:

```
source my_config/my_actual_bashrc.sh
```

Is there an equivalent with `.inputrc`, so my customizations can be in a separate location, and "called" by `~/.inputrc`?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

According to `man readline`:

**`$include`**

> *This directive takes a single filename as an argument and reads commands and bindings from that file.  For example, the following directive would read `/etc/inputrc`:*

```
$include  /etc/inputrc
```

Answer (score 6):

If you only want to change the location of the file, you can set `INPUTRC` to `my_config/my_actual_inputrc` (if unset, defaults to `~/.inputrc`).

There is also an equivalent of `source`, that is `$include` ([source](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Conditional-Init-Constructs.html#Conditional-Init-Constructs)). For example:

```
$include myconfig/my_actual_inputrc
```

Answer (score 5):

Another option is to use a link:

```
ln -s my_config/my_inputrc .inputrc
```

That will create the file `.inputrc` as a link pointing to `my_config/my_inputrc`.