# Ctrl-Backspace and Ctrl-Delete in bash

Tags: bash, terminal, keyboard-shortcuts, line-editor

Putting on Debian 8.3

```
stty werase '^H'
```

or on Arch Linux 2/2016

```
stty werase '^?'
```

in `.bashrc` (for example) makes <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Backspace</kbd> delete the last word in the terminal. Still it's not the same behavior as in modern GUI applications (e.g. Firefox): It deletes the last ***whitespace***-separated word, and not the last word separated by whitespace ***or*** characters like `. : , ; " ' & / ( )`.

Is it possible to make <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Backspace</kbd> behave in the terminal similar to modern GUI applications? Also, is there any way to make <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Delete</kbd> delete the word immediately before the cursor?

Comment: Your shell might support those actions, which could be bound to a given key.

Comment: @ThomasDickey: I'm using bash. It's fine if it works just in bash.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

There are two line editors at play here: the basic line editor provided by the kernel (canonical mode tty line editor), and bash's line editor (implemented via the readline library). Both of these have an erase-to-previous-word command which is bound to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> by default. The key can be configured for the canonical mode tty line editor through `stty werase`; bash imitates the key binding that it finds in the tty setting unless overridden in its own configuration.

The `werase` action in tty line editor cannot be configured. It always erases (ASCII) whitespace-delimited words. It's rare to interact with the tty line editor — it's what you get e.g. when you type `cat` with no argument. If you want fancy key bindings there, you can run the command under a tool like [rlwrap](http://utopia.knoware.nl/~hlub/rlwrap/#rlwrap) which uses readline.

Bash provides two [commands to delete the previous word](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Readline-Killing-Commands): `unix-word-rubout` (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd> or as set through `stty werase`), and `backward-kill-word` (`M-DEL`, i.e. <kbd>Esc</kbd> <kbd>Backspace</kbd>) which [treats a word as a sequence of alphanumeric characters in the current locale and `_`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/264816). If you want <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd> to erase the previous sequence of alphanumeric characters, don't set `stty werase`, and instead put the following line in your `.inputrc`:

```
"\C-h": backward-kill-word
```

Note that this assumes that your terminal sends the Ctrl+H character for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd>. Unfortunately it's one of those keys with no standard binding (and <kbd>Backspace</kbd> in particular [is a mess](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Keyboard-and-Console-HOWTO-5.html) for historical reasons).

There's also a symmetric command `kill-word` which is bound to `M-d` (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>) by default. To bind it to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd>, you first need to figure out what escape sequence your terminal sends, then add a corresponding line in your `.inputrc`. Type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd>; this will insert something like `^[[3;5~` where the initial `^[` is a visual representation of the escape character. Then the binding is

```
"\e[3;5~": kill-word
```

If you aren't happy with either definition of a word, you can provide your own in bash: see [confusing behavior of emacs-style keybindings in bash](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/150578/confusing-behavior-of-emacs-style-keybindings-in-bash/150591#150591)

Comment: excellent explanation ! The `Ctrl+Del` worked well. However, I cannot get `Ctrl+Backspace` to work. For `Ctrl+v, Ctrl+Backspace` my terminal says `^?`. What should I put in the `.inputrc` ? Thank you

Comment: @CiprianTomoiaga `"\C-?": backward-kill-word` or whatever readline function you want. But you can only define a binding for Ctrl+Backspace that's different from the binding for Backspace if they send different characters. If your terminal sends `^?` for both Backspace and Ctrl+Backspace, then the application running in the terminal has no way to distinguish them. Some terminals can be configured (e.g. xterm, urxvt), others (e.g. VTE-based terminal emulators) can't.

Comment: it's important to note that defining `~/.inputrc` disables the default `/etc/inputrc`. to fix this you have to include that file: `$include  /etc/inputrc` (from [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/179291/68186))

Comment: Wow. I've spent the last 10 years hating not having ctrl+del/ctrl+backspace in the terminal and the fix was a 2' config.

Comment: Using `\C-h` for both `kill-word` and `backward-kill-word` worked for me on Raspbian ‍♀️

Answer (score 16):

Try

<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>backspace</kbd>

In elementary OS it works like the way you want it (just like <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>backspace</kbd>)

Comment: Thanks for sharing, this is the simplest solution that works in Linux Mint too!

Answer (score 1):

The behaviour of the WERASE character in cooked mode terminal processing is [hardcoded](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/tty/n_tty.c#L1027), at least in Linux:

```c
           if (kill_type == WERASE) {
                   /* Equivalent to BSD's ALTWERASE. */
                   if (isalnum(c) || c == '_')
                           seen_alnums++;
                   else if (seen_alnums)
                           break;
           }
```

So words are letters, digits, and underscore. This is the way it will be at all times in a terminal on Linux when an application that does its own cooked mode processing is not running.

readline's version (used by bash and others) seems to be a little different than the kernel's version, but it also seems to be [hardcoded](http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/readline/rlman_14.html):

> Words are composed of letters and digits.

But this doesn't seem to match what `bash` actually does for me: `foo+bar^W` erases everything, not just `bar`. There is more information about that [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/78990/what-are-the-readline-word-separators).

Comment: 1. vi user is probably just looking for `backward-kill-word` (default binding `M-DEL`) instead of `unix-word-rubout`.

Answer (score -2):

You can use [AutoKey](https://github.com/autokey/autokey) with a "Window Filter" matching your terminal application to catch <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd> and do whatever with it.

For example do a `keyboard.send_keys("<ctrl>+w")` instead.

[image: autokey1]