# Find out if ctrl+backspace equals ctrl-H or ctrl-?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, tty, line-editor

[This question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/264791/ctrl-backspace-and-ctrl-delete-in-bash) was about how to delete the last word in bash with ctrl-backspace. As already mentioned there, different Linux distros (or different Unices in general) behave differently: Some produce `^H`, some produce `^?` if <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd> is pressed.

How can I find out in some automatic way (so it can be used in a script) which convention is followed?

Answer (score 2):

There is no standard way to ask about **control**-*backspace*.

The conventional way to ask about the *backspace* key is in the terminal database, e.g., look at the output of

```
tput kbs
```

If your terminal is configured to match the `TERM` value, that gives the "backspace" key.

Some terminals (originally `rxvt`, later [`xterm`](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.log.html#xterm_50) and now "several" undocumented) implement **control**-*backspace* as the "other" choice (`^H` where "backspace" sends `^?`, etc).  Some terminals ignore the control modifier.  But for those that use it, that inference is as far as you can go.

Further reading:

- [Why doesn't my delete key work?](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.faq.html#xterm_erase)

Comment: So there is absolutely no chance to simulate the keystroke (like with xdotool under X11) and save the result?

Comment: That wouldn't help if you're running in a virtual console, and also wouldn't help if you are running via ssh.

Comment: I know, just something similar.