# If statement in inputrc

Tags: readline, inputrc

I'm using a central location for my bashrc and source that for all my users like this:

```
GLOBAL_BASHRC="/path/to/global/bashrc"

if [ -r "$GLOBAL_BASHRC" -a -f "$GLOBAL_BASHRC" ]; then
    # Load the bashrc
    source $GLOBAL_BASHRC
else
    echo "Warning: Bashrc file [${GLOBAL_BASHRC}] does not exist!"
fi
```

And now I want to do the same thing for my inputrc file. I already found out how to do the equivalent to source in inputrc from [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/179291/how-to-call-a-sub-inputrc-like-in-bashrc-where-you-can-source-sub-script):

```
$include /path/to/global/inputrc
```

But the thing is, like in the bashrc above I want some error handling, I only want to load the file if it actually exists. Therefore my question is, how do I specify an if statement checking if a file exists in my inputrc?

Comment: http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/fto.html

Comment: @coffeMug I know about the file test operators for bash, but the question is, how do I use them in my .inputrc (which is loaded by readline)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to `$include` from your `~/.inputrc` as you can read an inputrc file at any time with

```
bind -f /path/to/global/inputrc
```

so use your usual `if [ -r file ]` with this instead of `source`.

---

The man page for says for an interactive login shell it reads `/etc/profile`
and the first found of `~/.bash_profile`, `~/.bash_login`, and `~/.profile`.
For other interactive shells it reads `~/.bashrc`, and for non-interactive it reads file `$BASH_ENV` if any.

In your case presumably you are using a non-login interactive shell for a terminal emulator, so `~/.bashrc` is read.  You can see what happens using `strace` and a dummy home, eg in `/tmp`.

```
$ touch /tmp/.inputrc /tmp/.bashrc
$ (unset BASH_ENV INPUTRC HISTFILE
   HOME=/tmp strace -e open -o /tmp/out bash -i)
```

This shows the following files being opened (I've removed some for brevity):

```
open("/tmp/.bashrc", O_RDONLY)          = 3
open("/tmp/.bash_history", O_RDONLY)    = -1 ENOENT
open("/tmp/.inputrc", O_RDONLY)         = 3
open("/tmp/.bash_history", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC, 0600) = 3
```

So bash will read `.inputrc` after `.bashrc`. This makes sense as it gives you time to set `INPUTRC` in your file.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than doing this in the `.inputrc` file (which has no facility for checking that the file actually exists AFAIK), you may set the `INPUTRC` environment variable in your `.bashrc` file:

```
if [ -r "$GLOBAL_BASHRC" -a -f "$GLOBAL_BASHRC" ]; then
    # Load the bashrc
    source $GLOBAL_BASHRC
    if [ -f /path/to/global/inputrc ]; then
        export INPUTRC="/path/to/global/inputrc"
    fi
else
    echo "Warning: Bashrc file [${GLOBAL_BASHRC}] does not exist!"
fi
```

The `INPUTRC` variable is documented in the `readline` manual (and in the `bash` manual too).

Comment: Yes, I am aware that I can change which INPUTRC file is used, but I want to load the global one AND set some local settings specific to the account / machine / whatever. So I'm adding the include as the first line in my inputrc and then add some other settings after that. So if I understand your answer right this is not possible?

Comment: @yzfr1 As far as I can work out, it is not possible to check in the `.inputrc` whether another file exists and then make a decision based on that test, no.